# Please help me out on this:Whitespace madness on Ubuntu's .sh files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have this code:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do
if [ $((i%3)) -equ 0 ] ; then
((i=i+1))
continue
fi
echo $i
((i=i+1))
done
#end
```

After I have compiled it is looping this message 100 times:

```
c2.sh: 4: [: 0: unexpected operator
0
```

I dont know where I am wrong tho maybe there are not enough/too many `whitespaces`? I dont know someone help me this Linux terminal case sensitivity is driving me nuts!

Comment: cut-n-paste your code, along with appropriate shebang (eg, `#!/bin/bash`) at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for assistance, though the error you're getting doesn't match what shellcheck is going to tell you so I'm wondering what shell you're using at the command line

Comment: Where is `-equ` documented as a valid test operator?

Comment: what do you mean by `compiled`? besides putting that code in a file, what other steps did you take to *compile* the script? how did you invoke the script?

Comment: chmod +x c2.sh  , sh c2.sh

Comment: omg @Shawn you are correct Lol!

Comment: Seems that a comment helped you find your answer. Would you like to create an answer post to share it?

Comment: Agree with @Shawn & Yunnosch. equ should be eq (or other valid op). Including the shebang would also have been helpful in most cases, but in this case I'm pretty sure the valid operators are common across *nix.

Comment: `sh c2.sh` is going to run the script under whatever shell is represented by `sh`; `sh` normally means `bourne shell` but in some environments `sh` is a symlink (or outright copy) of another shell (eg, `bash` or `dash`); under `bash` and `dash` your script generates the message: `./c2.sh: line 4: [: -equ: binary operator expected`

Comment: Since you are using bashisms (`((...))`, as identified by [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)) the shebang line should be `#! /bin/bash` (or similar).  You could also reduce the size of the code considerably by replacing it with `for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do ((i%3 == 0)) || echo "$i"; done`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put you original script into a test.sh file and made the subtle change to -equ

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
echo $i

while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do  
    if [ $(($i%3)) -eq 0 ] ; then
        ((i=$i+1))
        continue
    fi
    echo $i
    ((i=$i+1))
done
```

Some notes:

1. You need the following line at the top:

   #/bin/bash
2. You need to make the file executable by issuing the following:

   chmod +x

I think the above is what you were looking for?